# Conditional ordering based on field contents

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a SQL table that contains

```
ID
Title
Group Title
```

Everything has an `ID`, Everything has a `Title`, However only a few have a `Group Title`.
I want to pull off a list of records, But if `Group Title` exists I want that to overrule `Title`.
I then want to order the list by the result; So,
If I have three records

```
id           title          group title
1            Womble
2            Alphabet       Zebra
3            Mirror
```

The resulting result will be

```
id          result
3           Mirror
1           Womble
2           Zebra
```

How can I achieve this with a single query?

I suspect I need to do a select with a select though the following seems to work, but seems a bit 'hacky' and cheating

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS('',group_title,title) AS ordering,id,film_title,series_title 
FROM records 
ORDER BY ordering
```

So if `group title` is `NULL`, nothing appears, but if it does, then `group_title` is bolted onto the title. This field will never be displayed even though it looks ugly.

Comment: The only reason I cant use the above statement with confidence is if I have a mass upload of data, I cant guarantee someone will not have put a space in the group_title which will be added onto the front of the ordering result and affect the order

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want, I think you can use a query like this:

```
select 
    case when trim(coalesce(group_title, '')) = '' then 
        title 
    else 
        group_title 
    end ordering,
    id, film_title, series_title
from records 
order by ordering;
```

[`[ SQL Fiddle Demo ]`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d9ae44/3)